# rewiring a furnace for an inside fan

Tags: furnace

I have a **Outdoor AC unit that has an A-coil** in it, so it pushes all of the air from outside through huge duct work and into the ventilation, which by the time it gets to the last room its extremely weak.

But i also have a fan on my indoor furnace, but it's not hooked up to cooling, *The indoor fan only kicks on when the thermostat sends its 24 volts to the fan relay*

**My question:** Can i take the green wire from the furnace that normally goes to the thermostat and run it to the wall thermostat with the AC units green wire, so it gets a boots of air through the vents, or will i have to move the A-Coil into the furnace ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the indoor fan should run with the A/C and yes the green wire should power the fan relay, as long as the discharge from the outdoor unit is tied to the return system.  I looks like someone used a self-contained unit, usually installed in a mobile home instead of a unit that utilizes an "A" coil or slope coil mounted above the heating unit.

Comment: Also if I could I would move the A coil into the furnace. It's out of direct sunlight (radiant heat) and its closer to the cooling application.

Comment: I do not know how you are going to remove the "A" coil from the outside unit and reinstall it in the furnace plenum. Good luck doing that. I would rather purchase a new A/C unit  with a line set and "A" coil.